# Sustituir en java una cadena de letras que se encuentra con una posicion inicial y una final por "x"

Tags: java, string

Tengo el siguiente texto "gregeryh ehyrth ergedsrhgth erhrth" y lo que quiero es sustituir por X todos los valores que se encuentren desde la posición 20 a la 26, es decir, si entre la posicion 20 y la 26 hay 6 caracteres, que pasen a ser 6 "X"

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Para poder ayudarte necesitamos que adjuntes el codigo que llevas hecho o lo que has intentado en formato texto. Un saludo :)

Comment: Duplicado de su propia pregunta [StackOverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/331818/reemplazar-cadena-de-string-java-en-una-posición-concreta)